# Removing tab bar placeholder created by navigation controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar

I have a VC presented in a Nav controller, for some reason when pushing it, it creates a tab bar style placeholder.

As far as im aware the view isnt in a tabbarcontroller so im not sure why its being created. All views are programatic, no storyboards.

here is an image of the issue, is there a fix for this? i tried hiding tabbar on push but it had no effect

[image]

Comment: What makes you think that is a tab bar? It's probably the navigation controller's toolbar. [Edit] your question to include relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Your *navigationcontoller's* toolbar is not hidden.

Hide you NavigationController's toolbar.

**EDIT:**
Try this-
Swift:

```
self.navigationController?.toolbar.isHidden = true
```

As you have created Navigation Controller by code you can do it at the time of creation too:

```
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: myVC)
navController.toolbar.isHidden = true
```

Comment: how do i achieve that? use isHidden?

Comment: im afraid that has no effect ran in the viewwillappear of the vc

Comment: the second method didnt help either, no idea why

Comment: @jackdm see the edit again, the place where you created the navigation controller, is the place where you hide the toolbar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156105/discussion-between-subhajit-halder-and-jackdm).